# Building HMM for Kinect based gesture recognition

Tags: c#, algorithm, kinect, gesture-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I have a conceptional problem. I'm creating a program that uses Kinect for gesture recognition. I have some gesture data divided on categories (circles, swipes, etc.). For now I analyze only one hand. I record all the frames (30fps).

(*) For making my data discrete and position independent, I calculate angles between consecutive points.

Now I want to create `hidden Markov models` for each gesture type.

Now I need to determine a number of states for my `HMM`. How to do that? I thought about finding the longest gesture (in time). E.g. I have 3 gestures, first `1,2s`, second `1,4s` and third `1,5s`. So `1,5s` is the longest one. Now I want to apply (*) for each frame every 250 miliseconds (4 samples within a second). Because my longest gesture is `1,5s` long, so `NumberOfStatesForHMM = 1500ms / 250ms = 6 states` - and this should be pretty optimal?

I'm not sure how should I define states for `HMM`:/ If my idea above is correct, how to count transition probabilities when there are (e.g.) 6 states and one gesture ends after `1s`, so I analyze 4 states (probabilities of transitions from states 4 to 5 and 5 to 6 are equal to 0?).

I read [THIS](http://www.waset.org/journals/ijeee/v3/v3-3-26.pdf) paper, but I'm not quite sure how to solve my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on a similar dynamic hand gesture recognition project (although using a simpler webcam and not a Kinect). In my case, I categorized my gestures into classes say, Left, Right, Circular-Clockwise, Circular-AntiClockwise...etc. Since you would be taking angles between consecutive points into account, that would be your Observation Sequence. As for the states, there may not necessarily always be a logical relation between your States and Observation. I was working with 8 gestures. Now, I had about 12 observation symbols for each input pattern but the no. of states for each class was different. For example:
Left : 2 States
Right : 3 States
Circle clockwise : 4 States etc.

The advantage was that from the State Sequence output I got from Viterbi algo., I could directly get the maximum state number and hence, my Class. Also, during the learning phase, my Baum-Welch implementation automatically learnt the classes depending on the no. of states. You could refer to my blog post [which has a description of my approach to recognizing gestures using HMM as I did in my project] for addition information. I hope it helps you.

[Here is the Link](http://hcicv.blogspot.in/2012/07/hidden-markov-model-for-dummies.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about changing the number of states independly for each HMM, because e.g. I have about 15-20 observations for my Wave gestures, but only 5-8 for my Swipes. So if I had to choose max 4 states, because when I want to initialize my `A` (transitions matrix) for LR model, I count probabilities using formula `a_ii = 1 - N/T`, where `N` is a number of states and `T` is a gesture length (so when I choose a big `N` value, I get probability less than 0 for diagonals and more than 1 for diagonals + 1.

Comment: I have implemented `Forward-Backward Baum-Welch Learning` to estimate matrices and initial vector. It seems to work badly. I get 0 probability for completely bad cases for specified HMM (it should be like that), but when I learn my HMM with 3 samples and later I use one sample to evaluate the probability, I get likelihood like 3e-5. And it should be like about ~1. I'm doing something wrong,, maybe there's a mistake in somewhere or I need more data for learning. I need to test it empirically.

Comment: Btw. I'm in a job now, so I will have a look at your article later, but I can see for now it's really clearly described:) Ppl in their papers write such things that you need to think on it half a day. Gesture recognition should be pleasant, not a war with maths...

Comment: I totally agree with you Nickon that the research papers are cumbersome to understand (even the classical Rabiner Papers ;)). If you have lesses symbols for your swipes, might I suggest repeating each symbol atleast twice taking the total count to 10-16. This worked in my case [my linear gestures had far less observations that the curved swipes]. As for your testing data, I recommend getting as many samples as possible. Try performing each gesture a dozen times and learning over this data set. HMM performs miraculously with large data sets.

Comment: I have a question, could you PM me on nick0n8@gmail.com ?

Comment: I'm interested in the idea how to realise the LIVE gesture recognition. Could you help me?

Comment: ya sure I can try from whatever knowledge I have. What is it that you need help with exactly?